# Why does the selector in a angular component add classes?

Tags: angular, angular-router

Currently I am trying to understand Angular a bit better, especially under the hood. And I noticed that if I have Angular Router set up, and I am adding multiple selectors that these actualy get added. Because under the hood its all just 'ng-container' made by Angular Router.

I was wondering if someone has a bit more in-depth information about how this works? Because I don't realy understand how this is possible. According to angular the selector should be used to select HTML.

Kind regards

Edit: My question seemed to be unclear accoridng to MGX, so here is some more context then.

If you look at this sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-45-router-demo-forked-9d14bx?file=/src/app/product-list/product-list.component.ts

There is a product-list component. If I change the selector, the page breaks. Because angular wants me to put in a valid selector in the component decorator.

But if you look at this sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-45-router-demo-forked-h87emi?file=/src/app/product-list/product-list.component.ts

There is a router involved, and when I put in a random class 'monkey' into the selector. It suddenly gets added, instead of a breaking page.

So the question is: How does the angular router does this? And why does this work? Why wont this break.

Comment: Your question is unclear, please provide some code and what is shown in your browser to see what you did

Answer (score 0):

Add the *`<router-outlet></router-outlet>`* in your **app.component.html**

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>
</div>

<div>
  <product-list></product-list>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

updated demo link https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-45-router-demo-stackoverflow-5xd7zj?file=/src/app/app.component.html:68-232

Comment: Thats not the point, i want to know what that router outlet does to the components. Because I don't understand why components dont break if I add classes to the selector

Answer (score 0):

The component's class is used (`new ProductListComponent()`) when the component is instantiated via the Angular Router - that's why no matter what your selector is Angular will still render the component.

The component's selector is used when you reference a component in a HTML template - Angular has to find the component by selector in the components registry.

With the example given, if you want to render a component with selector `product-list .monkey` the following has to be present in the HTML template:

```html
// element matches a component from the registry by the `product-list .monkey` selector
<product-list class="monkey"></product-list>

// element can't be found because there's no component with such selector
<product-list></product-list>
```

Comment: Thats the entire premise of my question, because I do not need to add the monkey class inside the HTML for the selector to select it. The selector simply adds the monkey class to the HTML.